# Should I use push-to-connect fittings for PRV installation?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I have excessive water pressure and intend to install a **Pressure Reducing Valve** (PRV) on my 3/4" copper water line.

While looking at PRVs I noticed that some products feature SkarkBite push to connect fittings. I do not have all of the supplies I'd need to solder to the pipe so using a push to connect would save me from having to buy them. It may also be easier because I'd be working in my crawl space.

I live in central Alabama so we do not get many hard freezes, and the PRV will be in an enclosed crawl space that is warmer than the outside during the winter.

1. Are PTC connections reliable long term for high pressure applications?
2. Are there any other factors I should consider when deciding whether
   to solder in the PRV vs. use a Shark Bite?
3. In practice, how easy would it be to replace the PRV if I connected
   it with PTC fittings, and would it be better to have soldered on
   threaded adapters if I need to replace the PRV in 10-20 years?

*Edit:* I ended up buying and installing a PRV with Shark Bite fittings. Here is a photo of my finished installation. I didn’t notice when I asked the question originally that the ball valve that was already there was also installed with push to connect fittings.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SharkBite and other similar self-sealing insertion products are deemed reliable for long-term use (SharkBite are actually [guaranteed for 25 years](https://www.sharkbite.com/resources/blog/myth-vs-fact-closer-look-sharkbite-behind-wall-underground)). They're tried and true at this point, having been used for quite a few years. Of course, performance depends on your technique. It's important to de-burr and de-flare the pipe end.
2. The fact that you're installing a PRV isn't really relevant. Whether it's appropriate depends on your usage scenario and personal preference. Do you have space to work with this type of fitting? Are you willing to spend the money on them?
3. SharkBite connectors can be removed with proprietary tools or [DIY methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFEmVVYcxdQ). Whether that's a good strategy is entirely your prerogative.

Comment: Additionally, if the pressure at the high side is greater than 200 psi (unlikely) then a Sharkbite Push-To-Connect universal fitting might not be the best choice. Different products will have different ratings (as low as 80 psi) as well: http://pdf.lowes.com/installationguides/697285047068_install.pdf